# regular expression to set the unit test files path

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to regular expression 
I have a scenario where i need to set the files in my test case config file

```
    var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.store1.config.js');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [ 

               ],

        exclude: [],

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'html',
            dir: 'coverage/'
        },
```

I have series of components and each component has nested components

I want to have regular expression where it can find the test case file (anything.test.js) in each component level

below is the structure of my application[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put that `./**/*.test.js`.

It means that it will look recursively in all the folders for files with `.test.js` suffix.

Comment: Does it look into the child component as well?

Comment: Yes, the `**` tells that